# Why the details of my list is not showing in Details screen in outsystems

Tags: outsystems

I am very new to outsystems and I am trying to create a simple web app. I have a list screen that I created via dragging the entity on the interface. I created the details screen the same way. Why is that when I link the specific data on the list to display its details on the detail screen, it is not showing? Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you expand your question more on how it's not showing? Do you go to the detail page but the form's just empty? Or is it that when you click on the line on the list it doesn't navigate anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a listing and a detail screen by scaffolding, the usual behaviour is that one attribute will automatically be created as a link from the listing to the detail page. That will take care of the required things.

When you create the link manually, you need to make sure that you identify which variable maps to the identifier of that webpage. Usually, the detail page receives a parameter of type Identifier. You need to map the correct value to this parameter.

Checking OutSystems videos, the initial ones about designing screens will help you a lot.

Cheers!